# How to stop a powershell block after a timeout for powershell script

Tags: powershell, wmi, jobs

I want to invoke the command

```
$myArray = Get-Wmiobject -Class Win32-printer
```

But, on rare occasions, this command sometimes never fails nor succeed, returning the list of available printer.

I would like to assign $myArray only if the invocation takes less than a few seconds, lets say 5.  Otherwise, I want to display a dialog telling that printers are unavailable at this moment.

How to start a powershell block with a timeout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a job for that:

```
$job = Start-Job { Get-Wmiobject -Class Win32-printer }
$job | Wait-Job -Timeout 5
if ($job.State -eq 'Running') {
  # Job is still running, cancel it
  $job.StopJob()
} else {
  # Job completed normally, get the results
  $myArray = $job | Receive-Job
}
```

Comment: Job is not killed directly

Answer (score 1):

I would say to create your own customized WMI queries using type casting and the native .NET providers.  This way the work is still being done in the same opened console and you have physical control on the time outs.

I basically had the same frustration as you did.  I would be querying servers all day until I hit the one that had a broken WMI.  After so much, I started researching how to create my own WMI function to get around this.  That was my solution to the problem.  Learned a lot along the way.

Here is an article to help you along your way.

http://stevenmurawski.com/powershell/2009/01/dealing-with-wmi-timeouts/

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the above- powershell also has a built in stopwatch diagnostic for timeout functionality.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.03.heyscriptingguy.aspx